# Spring Cloud Gateway not returning correct Response code given by Downstream service (for file upload)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I have a simple downstream service for file upload. Sample code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController {

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam(value = "delay", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int delay) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
            "File Name => " + file.getOriginalFilename(),
            "File Size => " + file.getSize() + "bytes",
            "File Content Type => " + file.getContentType()));

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(delay);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(file.getName() + " uploaded");
    }

}
```

and a `CustomExceptionHandler` that returns `BAD_REQUEST` if there is a `MultipartException`:

```
@Configuration
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMultipartException(MultipartException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The size limit is 10MB in application.yml:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
```

If I upload a large file, it gives me a a `400` status as expected
[image: File serivce responsing 400]

When I try to hit the same via **spring cloud gateway** I get the following result:

[image]

and the logs shows following:

```
2019-11-08 00:36:10.797 ERROR 21904 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [86e57f7e] 500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/product-service/file/upload"

reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection has been closed BEFORE response, while sending request body
```

**Note** that the gateway is configured to take in large file size with `RequestSize` filter set globally to take way more than 10MB.

**How can I get the same response code as given by the downstream service?**

Also, I check with traditional Zuul, and i get a `500` error too.

**For the gateway**, for this particular case I know we can use the `RequestSize` filter and now the gateway will return the error code, but then we have to identify all the routes that expect this beforehand.
**Also, other validation in the API, like authorization, etc will have the same the same issue. The response code produced because of these validations will not propagate up**.

Sample code spring-cloud-gateway/product-service/eureka - https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-cloud/tree/master/spring-routing

Answer (score 0):

can you try to go through a non limitation of the volume of the file directly to without going through the getway? try the value -1 for the properties :

properties file of the MS where you want to upload the file

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size =-1

spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size =-1
```

if it good, it may give a problem with the zuul proxy's ribbon socket size, there are properties informed for this type of situation, the following:

Properties file of the getway :

```
ribbon.eager-load.enabled=true
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=3999996
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=999999
ribbon.ReadTimeout=999999
ribbon.SocketTimeout=999999
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=999999
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=999999
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```